# Footer outside page margins

Tags: header-footer

My footer is outside page margins. It should be inside, no matter my page geometry.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{My Name}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{University}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you want to add the `includefoot` option to `geometry`.

Comment: Look at the console output. `fancyhdr` will tell you not only that it doesn't have room for things, but just how much more room you need to provide it with. It will also warn you that the output may be inconsistent due to on-the-fly changes it makes to try to accommodate your headers/footers.

Comment: @egreg write your comment as answer, you deserve it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `bottom=1cm`, `geometry` will set up things so that the last line in the text block is 1cm from the page boundary and, of course, this pushes the footer down.

The `includefoot` option will tell `geometry` that *the footer* must have its baseline at 1cm from the page boundary.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[
  left=1cm,
  right=1cm,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=1cm,
  includefoot,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyfoot[L]{My Name}
\fancyfoot[C}{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{University}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I also added `heightrounded` that will ensure (possibly with a slight change to the text block height) an integral number of lines on the page. I also changed the “old” syntax for `fancyhdr` to the “modern” one.

For producing the image below, I added the `showframe` option to `geometry`, just to better show the various parts. The additional lines will not appear on your document.

[image]